# Parse a text file to a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, r, data-structures, dictionary

I have a text file holding data in this format:

```
    21-Jun-2013 22:12:52:137, INFO, *********************************************************************
    21-Jun-2013 22:12:52:137, INFO, Data being shown
    21-Jun-2013 22:12:52:137, INFO, *********************************************************************
    21-Jun-2013 22:12:52:137, INFO, Meta-data
    21-Jun-2013 22:12:52:137, INFO, Meta-data
    21-Jun-2013 22:12:52:137, INFO, Exp                           1                         2    
    21-Jun-2013 22:12:52:168, INFO, -------------------------------------------------------------
    21-Jun-2013 22:12:52:184, INFO, 1           0.00000 *   1.00000       0.00000 *   1.00000    
    21-Jun-2013 22:12:31:919, INFO, 2           0.00000 *   1.00000       0.00000 *   2.00000
    21-Jun-2013 22:12:31:997, INFO, 3           0.00000 *   5.33380       0.00000 *   5.33380
    21-Jun-2013 22:12:32:059, INFO, 4           0.00000 *   0.00000       0.00000 *   0.00000
    21-Jun-2013 22:12:32:137, INFO, 5           0.00000 *   0.00000       0.00000 *   0.00000
```

This file is an event-log of a program and it is used to debug the program. Each line starts with the time stamp. The first 5 lines of the file has the meta-data relating to the text file and it is not of interest. The data to be analyzed starts at line 6. Line 6 is the header for the columns. The first column `Exp` stores a row-id for the data. The subsequent columns-headers are nothing but the column-ids. The data in each of these columns are 2 quantities being multiplied (say A*B). The actual data has column-ids to the order of thousand and row-ids to the order of a few million.

Now, I want to process this data using `R` or `Python` to generate a list of dictionaries. For the given example I want a list of dictionary like this:

```
    expressionList = [ row1 , row2 , row3, row4, row5 ]
```

Each element in the list should be a dictionary. The expanded form of each elements is shown below:

```
    row1   = { 'col1A': 0.00000, 'col1B': 1.00000, 'col2A': 0.00000, 'col2B': 1.00000 }
    row2   = { 'col1A': 0.00000, 'col1B': 1.00000, 'col2A': 0.00000, 'col2B': 2.00000 }
    row3   = { 'col1A': 0.00000, 'col1B': 5.33380, 'col2A': 0.00000, 'col2B': 5.33380 }
    row4   = { 'col1A': 0.00000, 'col1B': 0.00000, 'col2A': 0.00000, 'col2B': 0.00000 }
    row5   = { 'col1A': 0.00000, 'col1B': 0.00000, 'col2A': 0.00000, 'col2B': 0.00000 }
```

I am very new to both these programming languages - any help/guidance with this greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to drop the timestamps?  Also there are no `dictionaries` in `R` only nested named `lists`.

Comment: The time-stamp should be dropped. I was not aware of that limitation in `R`. Essentially, I want to be able to query `expressionList[row1][1A]` or `expressionList[row1][1B]` to retrieve the value A or B.

Comment: This tutorial might interest you: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/modules/raw_data.htm In your case, `read.table(text="your text")` seems to work fine. Type `?read.table` at the R console to see documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in a comment `read.table` should work on your data.

Here's an example. Your text file has been saved as "mytest.txt" in my home directory. Substitute that with the actual path to your file. We've specified "`skip = 7`" to drop the first few lines:

```
mydf <- read.table("~/mytest.txt", skip=7)
mydf
#            V1            V2    V3 V4 V5 V6     V7 V8 V9    V10
# 1 21-Jun-2013 22:12:52:184, INFO,  1  0  * 1.0000  0  * 1.0000
# 2 21-Jun-2013 22:12:31:919, INFO,  2  0  * 1.0000  0  * 2.0000
# 3 21-Jun-2013 22:12:31:997, INFO,  3  0  * 5.3338  0  * 5.3338
# 4 21-Jun-2013 22:12:32:059, INFO,  4  0  * 0.0000  0  * 0.0000
# 5 21-Jun-2013 22:12:32:137, INFO,  5  0  * 0.0000  0  * 0.0000
```

You can subset columns in R using a vector of `TRUE` and `FALSE`. Here, the pattern appears to be a set of four columns we want to drop, followed by a "keep, drop, keep" pattern.

```
## Create the vector of what we want to keep (TRUE) and drop (FALSE)
keepdrop <- c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, rep(c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE),
              length.out=length(mydf)-4))
## Subset to drop the unwanted columns
mydf <- mydf[keepdrop]

## Let's make some nicer names
cols <- length(mydf) %/% 2
names(mydf) <- paste("col", sequence(cols), 
                     rep(c("A", "B"), each = cols), 
                     sep = "_")

## The final output
mydf
#   col_1_A col_2_A col_1_B col_2_B
# 1       0  1.0000       0  1.0000
# 2       0  1.0000       0  2.0000
# 3       0  5.3338       0  5.3338
# 4       0  0.0000       0  0.0000
# 5       0  0.0000       0  0.0000
```

From here, accessing information is pretty straightforward:

```
### Third row
mydf[3, ]
#   col_1_A col_2_A col_1_B col_2_B
# 3       0  5.3338       0  5.3338

### Second column, as a data.frame, by position
mydf[, 2, drop = FALSE]
#   col_2_A
# 1  1.0000
# 2  1.0000
# 3  5.3338
# 4  0.0000
# 5  0.0000

### Fourth column, as a vector, by name
mydf[, "col_2_B"]
# [1] 1.0000 2.0000 5.3338 0.0000 0.0000
```

In addition to this, you might want to look into the `fread` function from the "data.table" package, which would be helpful in reading in large data more quickly.

Comment: Excellent answer! Based on @Frank's comment I found a temporary solution using read.fwf. But it involved a lot of hard coding. This piece here is very robust! Thanks much!

Comment: @RazorXsr, the file seems fairly regularly structured. The other approach I would have suggested would be to use `sed` to do some pre-processing that would make it easier to import the file in a variety of places.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care too much about the timestamps, I'd suggest using numpy's loadtxt function.

```
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt('test.txt', skiprows=7, usecols=(4,6,7,9),
            dtype={'names':   ('col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'),
                   'formats': ('f4',   'f4',   'f4',   'f4')})
```

This gives you a whole bunch of ways to access your data:

```
print data[0]
print data['col2']
print data['col2'][2:]
print data['col2'][2]
print data[2]['col2']
print data[2][1]
```

(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0)

[ 1.          1.          5.33379984  0.          0.        ]

[ 5.33379984  0.          0.        ]

5.3338

5.3338

5.3338

-

If you want to keep the timestamps, you can always store them as strings and parse them later on.

Oh, and watch out for missing values! The parser probably won't like them (unless they have the same data type as the values themselves).  Numpy's genfromtxt function has ways of dealing with them, although I haven't done much with it. It's basically loadtxt on steroids.